# Rendering Threejs in React dissapears my root element in HTML

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js

I'm trying to use Three.js in Typescript react, I render Dodecahedron figure and random stars, I want to add some mark up to my three.js with React but when I render Three.js canvas into HTML it dissapears my root div, and I'm not able to add some other components

**THREE.JS**

```js
import * as THREE from "three";

export function ThreeCanvas() {
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.innerHTML = "";
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronBufferGeometry(1.7, 0);
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: "#00FF95",
  });

  const Stars = () => {
    const starGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 24, 24)
    const starMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0xffffff})
    const star = new THREE.Mesh(starGeometry, starMaterial)

    const [x, y, z] = Array(3).fill(1).map(() => THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(70))
    star.position.set(x, y, z)

    scene.add(star)
  }

  Array(200).fill(100).forEach(Stars)

  const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff)
  light.position.set(20, 20, 20)
  scene.add(light)

  camera.position.z = 5;
  camera.position.x = 3.5

  const Figure = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(Figure);

  const animate = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    Figure.rotation.x += 0.01;
    Figure.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };

  animate();

  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
  
  return null
}
```

this is my three.js code what I do in react

**React**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { ThreeCanvas } from "./Components/Three";
import Landing  from "./Components/Landing";
import "./Style/Style.css"

const FirstSection = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Landing />
      <ThreeCanvas />;
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<FirstSection />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Landing is my markup component when I open console I dont see anywhere my Landing element but in react tools I see, how to fix that issue I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing document.body in Three.JS component which is why the body only contains the canvas. You might want to use a reference to the element instead of targeting document.body so that it's not disturbing the DOM structure which is why your markdown does not show. As a rule of thumb, you should never be interacting with the DOM via the document.

```
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
```

I've quickly refactored the Three.JS component to use a React element reference so that you can add additional markup.

### Refactored ThreeCanvas Component

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";

export function ThreeCanvas() {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!loaded && ref) {
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
      );

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

      const geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronBufferGeometry(1.7, 0);
      const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: "#00FF95"
      });

      const Stars = () => {
        const starGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 24, 24);
        const starMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
          color: 0xffffff
        });
        const star = new THREE.Mesh(starGeometry, starMaterial);

        const [x, y, z] = Array(3)
          .fill(1)
          .map(() => THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(70));
        star.position.set(x, y, z);

        scene.add(star);
      };

      Array(200).fill(100).forEach(Stars);

      const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
      light.position.set(20, 20, 20);
      scene.add(light);

      camera.position.z = 5;
      camera.position.x = 3.5;

      const Figure = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

      scene.add(Figure);

      const animate = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        Figure.rotation.x += 0.01;
        Figure.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      const resize = () => {
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      };

      animate();
      ref.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
      setLoaded(true);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", resize);
    }
  }, [ref, loaded]);

  return <div ref={ref} />;
}

export default ThreeCanvas;
```

#### Typescript Version: ThreeCanvas.tsx

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";

export function ThreeCanvas() {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!loaded && ref.current) {
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
      );

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

      const geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronBufferGeometry(1.7, 0);
      const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: "#00FF95"
      });

      const Stars = () => {
        const starGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 24, 24);
        const starMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
          color: 0xffffff
        });
        const star = new THREE.Mesh(starGeometry, starMaterial);

        const [x, y, z] = Array(3)
          .fill(1)
          .map(() => THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(70));
        star.position.set(x, y, z);

        scene.add(star);
      };

      Array(200).fill(100).forEach(Stars);

      const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
      light.position.set(20, 20, 20);
      scene.add(light);

      camera.position.z = 5;
      camera.position.x = 3.5;

      const Figure = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

      scene.add(Figure);

      const animate = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        Figure.rotation.x += 0.01;
        Figure.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      const resize = () => {
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      };

      animate();
      ref.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
      setLoaded(true);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", resize);
    }
  }, [ref, loaded]);

  return <div ref={ref} />;
}

export default ThreeCanvas;
```

Comment: Thank you very much also I will add some quick fix if someone uses Typescript React, on Typescript React with this code you will get type error, `Object is possibly 'undefined'` on `ref.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement)` to fix that just write `const ref = React.useRef<any>();` to manualy dissapear error

Comment: @callmenikk I've updated the answer with the correct typings for Typescript, I would recommend using that instead of setting any.